# Set default date (in other formats) in a DatePicker - Android

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I made a DatePicker which should let the users select a date following the Italian standards, which means DD-MM-YYYY. The default one should be: 01-01-2000, but I get 01-01-1900 instead.

This is my code:

```
      dateSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            final Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.MySpinnerDatePickerStyle, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

                    c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 01);
                    c1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 01);
                    c1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000);
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    eta = dateFormat.format(c1.getTime());
                }
            }, mDay, mMonth, mYear);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your variables `mYear`, `mMonth` and `mDay` to the values you require.

They are the ones that populate the `DatePickerDialog`.